# How to deploy pass env into docker-compose when deploy into production on nestjs

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, nestjs, google-cloud-run

I use **docker** , **docker-compose** and **nestjs** deploy into prod. Prod running on Cloud Run.
Docker file look like

```
###################
# BUILD FOR LOCAL DEVELOPMENT
###################

FROM node:18-alpine As development

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy application dependency manifests to the container image.
# A wildcard is used to ensure copying both package.json AND package-lock.json (when available).
# Copying this first prevents re-running npm install on every code change.
COPY --chown=node:node package*.json ./

# Install app dependencies using the `npm ci` command instead of `npm install`
RUN npm ci

# Bundle app source
COPY --chown=node:node . .

# Use the node user from the image (instead of the root user)
USER node

###################
# BUILD FOR PRODUCTION
###################

FROM node:18-alpine As build

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY --chown=node:node package*.json ./

# In order to run `npm run build` we need access to the Nest CLI which is a dev dependency. In the previous development stage we ran `npm ci` which installed all dependencies, so we can copy over the node_modules directory from the development image
COPY --chown=node:node --from=development /usr/src/app/node_modules ./node_modules

COPY --chown=node:node . .

# Run the build command which creates the production bundle
RUN npm run build

# Set NODE_ENV environment variable
ENV NODE_ENV production

# Running `npm ci` removes the existing node_modules directory and passing in --only=production ensures that only the production dependencies are installed. This ensures that the node_modules directory is as optimized as possible
RUN npm ci --only=production && npm cache clean --force

USER node

###################
# PRODUCTION
###################

FROM node:18-alpine As production

# Copy the bundled code from the build stage to the production image
COPY --chown=node:node --from=build /usr/src/app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --chown=node:node --from=build /usr/src/app/dist ./dist

# Start the server using the production build
CMD [ "node", "dist/main.js" ]
```

**Docker compose**

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  postgres:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/db/Dockerfile
    container_name: postgres
    ports:
      - '${DB_HOST_PORT}:5432'
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  api:
      container_name: nestjs
      image: nestjs-dev
      restart: unless-stopped
      build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
        target: development
      # Mount host directory to docker container to support watch mode
      volumes:
        - .:/app
        # This ensures that the NestJS container manages the node_modules folder
        # rather than synchronizes it with the host machine
        - /app/node_modules
      ports:
        - '${NEST_JS_PORT}:3000'
      depends_on:
        - postgres


volumes:
  db_data:
```

My project have three file : **.env.dev(develop)**, .**env.stg(stg)** , **.env.prod(production)**
Now i want deploy my project into **cloud run(production)** with environment **.env.prod** How to use pass **.env.prod** into **docker-compose** and deploy it into production ?. When i check some example, i must create two file docker-compose and deploy it. What best way deploy into product when using production ? Thanks you.

Comment: Can you have look at this [Document](https://www.tomray.dev/deploy-nestjs-cloud-run) and this [Stackoverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73254576/18265702).

Comment: Yes i has look it. But when i deploy into cloud run my env not save on local. I want cloud run control my key. Currently I have to prepare the env variables on cloud run in advance, right?

Comment: @SandeepVokkareni

Comment: You can use the `.env` file and let docker know about the `.env` file using this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69025876/18265702).